# How to get Mathematica to evaluate trig function derivatives in a expression

Tags: symbolic

I am working on a problem that results in expressions with trig functions and their derivatives along with several other functions and derivatives.  At one point, the subtraction of two expressions resulted in an expression proportional to 1 + sin''[x] / sin[x] whose value is obviously zero. How do I get Mathematica to evaluate the second derivative and thus reduce this expression to the value zero?  This is just an example of a more general problem of long expressions in which I would like all the symbolic derivatives to be replaced by their values.

Comment: Please provide your code, since _Mathematica_ does automatically simplify `1 + Sin''[x]/Sin[x]` to `0`. Please also note that `Sin[x]` is not the same as `sin[x]`, and the built-in Mathematica functions always start with capital letters.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  You were correct to suggest that the problem was Sin[x] vs sin[x].  I am new to Math'ca and in this case, I started with a matrix of functions that I defined that contained trig functions and didn't realize that Math'ca wouldn't know what I meant when I used sin[x], etc.